# Permissions of a team member in iPhone Developer Portal

Tags: iphone, iphone-developer-program, ios-provisioning

I want to know if there is a possibility to add a team member in iPhone Developer Portal that will have permissions (see / modify / update) ONLY to one application.

The reason - there is a big company (that has many applications in the App Store) that uploaded one of my applications and I have hard time to send an update to the application (can't access the guy that is responsible for all the iPhone applications).
I want to ask them to add me as a team member, but they might agree only if I won't be able to see/touch any other application except the one that I have developed...

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

I don't believe this is possible; there are no per-app permissions.

The available "roles" are explained here:

http://developer.apple.com/programs/roles/index.php

It seems a bit odd if they trust you to write an application that they've published under their corporate identity, but don't trust that you'll only change what you're meant to. Either way is seems the only solution to your problem is likely to be a non-technical one; you need to find a way to get to that guy, whether it's appealing to his better nature, or finding a path to someone more senior who can lean on him.

Comment: First of all it's not that they trust me to develop the app for them - I trust them to upload my app on their account. Actually, it's even not me - it's my client (small start-up) that trusts the huge corporate to publish the app that I develop on their account in order to promote it.

Comment: In addition, I think that it would be very useful. I see one more use in this (access to one application only): many of my clients want to access the app info after the app is stored on my company's account. And I don't think that I should give them access to all the applications stored in this account. Other clients won't be happy about it. Business can't be built on trust.

Comment: Ah, I understand your position a bit better now. It would seem like your client's trust is misplaced if you can't get the corporate to upload new versions :-) I think the Apple position on this would be that each company should publish apps using their own account. You can ask for help / suggest your feature using http://developer.apple.com/contact/ but I think you probably need to look for a different solution in the short/medium term. (I know that's not want you want to hear.)